# Plural affix in the Oxford English Dictionary

Tags: grammatical-number, dictionaries, affixes, morphemes

I cannot find an entry for the plural affix in the OED (*-es, -s , 's, s*), unlike say for -[en](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00074421).

Also for -ed we have : [-ed, suffix1](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00072077), [-ed, suffix2](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00072078), [-d](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00056947), [-t, suffix1](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00245745), [-t, suffix2](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00245746), etc.

What are the lexicographical reasons for it? If somebody could check the paywalled current version, it would surely clarify this issue

Comment: One might say that this is not an affix but part of the declension of the noun (the only part that remains in English, in fact).

Comment: @PeterShor see edits. Even so, where can such an info. be found in the OED?

Comment: I'm surprised that they include -en but not say -s.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth the 3rd edition should have gotten to the letter S by now, because:
_Beginning with the launch of the first OED Online site in 2000, the editors of the dictionary began a major revision project to create a completely revised third edition of the dictionary (OED3), expected to be completed in 2037. **Revisions were started at the letter M.**_